# openxml how to read an inlineStr with an OpenXmlReader

Tags: excel, excel-2007, openxml, openxml-sdk

I have the following code:

```
public static void ReadExcelFileSAX(string filename)
{
    using (SpreadsheetDocument myDoc = SpreadsheetDocument.Open(filename, true))
    {
        WorkbookPart workbookPart = myDoc.WorkbookPart;
        WorksheetPart worksheetPart = workbookPart.WorksheetParts.First();

        OpenXmlReader reader = OpenXmlReader.Create(worksheetPart);
        string text;
        while (reader.Read())
        {
           if (reader.ElementType == typeof(CellValue))
           {
                text = reader.GetText();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

This code can read any cell where the data type is a number, but it cannot read  *inlineStr*

Looking at the XML with Productivity tool, I think the code can read the following XML

```
<x:c r="D2" t="n">
    <x:v>328</x:v>
</x:c>
```

But it can't read the this one (or I don't know how to do it)

```
<x:c r="F1" s="6" t="inlineStr">
    <x:is>
        <x:t>T1</x:t>
    </x:is>
</x:c>
```

Any help will be appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: Do you get any errors or just get a blank string when reading inlineStr values?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your code look like it should read the values correctly, but some more information would be useful to detect the cause of the issue.

I suppose you can try to check if the type is `InlineString`, but you can't just use `GetText()` method, because `InlineString` is not dervide from `OpenXMlLeafTextElement`.

I haven't tested this yet, but I suggest you to try:

```
while (reader.Read())
{
   if (reader.ElementType == typeof(CellValue))
   {
        text = reader.GetText();
   }
   else if (reader.ElementType == typeof(InlineString)) //or instead of this, check type of its child node and use it inside this if statement
   {
        text = (reader.LoadCurrentElement() as InlineString).Text.Text;
   }
}
```

Or something similiar to this. If you have any issues with this code, let me know, so I'll correct it.

Some references:

- http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/documentformat.openxml.openxmlreader_members.aspx
- http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/documentformat.openxml.openxmlreader.loadcurrentelement.aspx
- http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/documentformat.openxml.spreadsheet.inlinestring.aspx